# Modificar registro de una tabla php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola estoy necesitando modificar registros de mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen necesito realizar un formulario para agregar el ESTADO y COMENTARIO con la opción Dar Reporte, ya que lo he estado intentando y ningun metodo ha funcionado

Este es mi codigo tambien,si es posible orientarme para realizar esta modificacion

```
                    <?php
                        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM mensaje WHERE destinatario='$usuarioingresado'";
                        $ejecutarConsulta = mysqli_query($mysqli, $consulta);
                        $verFilas = mysqli_num_rows($ejecutarConsulta);
                        $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta);

                        if(!$ejecutarConsulta){
                            echo"Error en la consulta";
                        }else{
                            if($verFilas<1){
                                echo"<tr><td>Sin registros</td></tr>";
                            }else{
                                for($i=0; $i<=$fila; $i++){
                                    echo'
                                        <tr> 
                      <td>'.$fila[0].'</td>
                      <td>'.$fila[1].'</td>
                      <td>'.$fila[2].'</td>
                      <td>'.$fila[3].'</td>
                      <td>'.$fila[4].'</td>
                      <td>'.$fila[5].'</td>
                      <td>'.$fila[6].'</td>
                      <td>'.$fila[7].'</td>
                      <td>'.$fila[8].'</td>
                      <td>
                      <a href="editartareas.php">Dar Reporte</a>
                      </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ';
                                    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ?>              
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Seria bueno que comentaras cuales fueron los metodos que utilizaste y no funcionaron, porque a pesar de que lo que pides es algo "sencillo" requiere de una explicación un poco larga para que logres entender como funciona ese paso de edición, y por alli hay muchas maneras que no necesariamente deberiamos decirte, si colocas los metodos utilizados probablemente se te pueda ayudar mucho más facil

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenes dos opciones dependiendo si lo queres pasar por GET (que aparezca en la URL) o por POST (Que vaya en el cuerpo de la solicitud http).

En primer lugar sacaria el echo del principio y directamente agregaria un **?>** (cierre de etiqueta PHP) y ahi agregaria el html que quiero se repita, modificando tambien los  para que queden asi 
De esta forma podemos usar con un poco mas de comodidad las comillas dobles y simples.

Quedaria asi:

```
 for($i=0; $i<=$fila; $i++){

                           ?>
                                <tr> 
              <td><?php echo $fila[0] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[1] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[2] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[3] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[4] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[5] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[6] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[7] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[8] ?></td>
              <td>
              <a href="editartareas.php">Dar Reporte</a>
              </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php
                            $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta);
                        }
```

Despues de eso:
Si queres mandarlo por POST la forma mas facil es agregar un formulario en cada iteracion del FOR, antes de todos los  agrega un  y agregale un
`<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fila[8] ?>" name="id">`
y en el ultimo td en lugar de un href pones un

```
<input type="submit" value="Dar reporte">
```

(Y acordarte de cerrar el form despues del ultimo td).

Quedaria asi:
for($i=0; $i<=$fila; $i++){

```
                           ?>
                                <tr> 
<form method="POST" action="editartareas.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $fila[8]?>">
              <td><?php echo $fila[0] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[1] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[2] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[3] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[4] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[5] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[6] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[7] ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $fila[8] ?></td>
              <td>
              <input type="submit" value="Dar Reporte">
              </td>
</form>
                                </tr>
                            <?php
                            $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutarConsulta);
                        }
```

Esto va a permitir que te llegue el ID del post que queres modificar en la variable **$_POST['id']** para que puedas utilizarlo como clave en la sentencia SQL de UPDATE.

Sino, tambien podes, en el href modificarlo para que sea

```
<a href="editartareas.php?id='.$fila[8].">
```

De esta forma te va a mandar el ID en una variable $_GET['id'] para que puedas utilizarlo como clave en la sentencia SQL de UPDATE.

Espero haberlo explicado bien!!!

Saludos!

Comment: Se entendio perfecto, muchas gracias, estoy intentando realizar la sentencia SQL, pero al darle editar me arroja error al parecer de sintaxis